# how can add only one data?

Tags: java, rest, put

```
@PutMapping("/api/cricketer/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Cricketer> updateCricketer(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody Cricketer cricketer) {
    Cricketer cCricketer = cricketerService.findById(id);
    cCricketer.setCountry(cricketer.getCountry());
    cCricketer.setName(cricketer.getName());
    cCricketer.setHighestScore(cricketer.getHighestScore());
    cricketerRepository.save(cCricketer);
    return new ResponseEntity<Cricketer>(cricketer, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Hello everyone. When I try to update a data on updateCricketer method, it updates the data as I entered. But other datas turn as null. Does anyone know how can I solve that problem?

Comment: Did you try cricketerRepository.update(cCricketer); instead of cricketerRepository.save(cCricketer); ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. "But other data turns as null". What do you mean by that? In other words: show a complete example including expected and actual output.

Comment: Hi @yefesin. Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? Did you put a breakpoint and inspect the received values?

Answer (score 0):

Do a null check before setting values.

```
@PutMapping("/api/cricketer/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> updateCricketer(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody Cricketer cricketer) {
    Cricketer cCricketer = cricketerService.findById(id);
    if(Objects.nonNull(cCricketer)) {
        cCricketer.setCountry(Objects.isNull(cricketer.getCountry()) ? cCricketer.getCountry() : cricketer.getCountry());
        cCricketer.setName(Objects.isNull(cricketer.getName()) ? cCricketer.getName() : cricketer.getName());
        cCricketer.setHighestScore(Objects.isNull(cricketer.getHighestScore()) ? cCricketer.getHighestScore() : cricketer.getHighestScore());
        // Do same to the rest of the fields

        cricketerRepository.save(cCricketer);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(cricketer, HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("No cricketer Found!", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to try for id

Comment: I've edited the answer. No. you do not need to try it for id.

Comment: I try it, but I just want the data I entered to change, but the data I didn't enter is null.So İ just entering the name,name is chancing but country and HighestScore becoming null

Comment: `Cricketer cCricketer = cricketerService.findById(id);` In here cCricketer country and HighestScore are null or not?

Comment: Country and HighestScore not null but entering the name becoming null

Comment: If database name is null and also request name value is null then db value won't change. But if you're sending correct request there shouldn't be any issues. can you add your sample request ?

Comment: {             
          {           
            "id":"5",
            "name":"yefesin",
            "country":"Country",
            "highestScore":"7"
               }
            
               }Values like that and just want change to HighestScore {"highestScore":"10"}after then becoming like that{
    "id": null,
    "name": null,
    "country": null,
    "highestScore": "10"
}

Comment: In this case you might need to add this check to the id field as well. otherwise it will be null. then whole object will be null.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for this is to use data transfer objects and an object mapper which will take care of the null check depending on the strategy that you decide.

http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mapping-result-for-null-arguments